# Is there a way to make a jquery animate opacity not use a lot of CPU?

Tags: jquery

I've made a button with `mouseenter(opacity:0.6)` and `mouseleave(opacity:1)`, it uses only 6% of cpu when running on Firefox or Chrome but in IE8 it uses 35% 42% ...

Is there some way to make it not use a lot of CPU in IE?

Comment: Welcome to the world of web development where IE is your greatest tormentor. :)

Comment: IE is the bane of my existence. Microsoft is the reason everyone isn't a web designer.

Answer (score 1):

IE8 is fairly old browser. You have three options:

1. Don't use IE.
2. Don't use opacity in IE.
3. Use images instead of opacity.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you can try a different "Easing" string to indicate which method of animation you want to use. My guess would be that Linear would be less intensive than the default "swing". It also mentions being able to use mentions being able to use plugins to use other "Easing" methods. It's possible there are less intensive methods of doing the animation. You can also try decreasing the duration or span of opacities that must be covered.

http://api.jquery.com/animate/